# Change a GET parameter in URL in Razor MVC

Tags: url, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a paging script in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I would like to be able to take the current URL of a page

```
 /Cards/Search?Page=&Terms=&Display=false
```

and change the value of the Page parameter. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it does work for what I am doing:

```
RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
foreach(string item in Request.QueryString){
    if (item != "Page") { rvd.Add(item, Request[item]); }
} 
rvd.Add("Page", 1);

Url.Action("Action", rvd)
```

Answer (score -1):

Suggest you check out what RouetConfig is how it works.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing

Start here global.asax

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // Research this
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Nothing stops you calling your controller actions.
You can also redirect there

```
RedirectToAction("Action","controller");
```

or just outright redirect...

```
Redirect(myHackedUrl);
```

There is also a very useful tool at IIS level for managing redirects, if this is a somewhat more concrete permananet rule.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect to a different controller, I am trying to change the value of a GET parameter.